# Send String Query With Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Because my previous question was not answered, I decided to ask my question another way.
I'm trying to send string query to server with retrofit. but the response is null. How to send String query with retrofit?
When i try the exact URL in browser everything works fine. but the URL that retrofit sends not work. i have to write "search" query Manual.

This is the interface:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("get_near_shop_cat.php")
    Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getNearShopBySearch(@Field("lat") Double lat, @Field("lng") Double lng, @Field("search") String search);
```

This is my calls:

```
private Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getObservableNearShopBySerach(Double lat,Double lng,String search){
    return NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(NetworkInterface.class)
            .getNearShopBySearch(lat,lng,search)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

private DisposableObserver<NearShopLocationModel> getObserverNearShop(){
    return new DisposableObserver<NearShopLocationModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(NearShopLocationModel nearShopLocationModel) {
            smvi.getNearShop(nearShopLocationModel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            String a=e.getMessage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            smvi.isAllDataLoad(true);
        }
    };
}
```

And this is the php code from server:

```
<?php 

//Importing the database connection 
require_once('DBconnect.php');

$lat = $_GET['lat'];    
$lng = $_GET['lng'];    
$search = $_GET["search"];  

    //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
    $sql = "SELECT id,title,imageURL1,comment,categoryName,lat,lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) 
    AS distance FROM shop WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%',$search, '%') || categoryName LIKE CONCAT('%',$search, '%') HAVING distance < 5";

    //Getting result 
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

    //Adding results to an array 
    $results = array(); 


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            array_push($results, array(
            "id"=>$row['id'],
            "title"=>$row['title'],
            "imageURL1"=>$row['imageURL1'],
            "comment"=>$row['comment'],
            "categoryName"=>$row['categoryName'],
            "lat"=>$row['lat'],
            "lng"=>$row['lng']
            )
            );

    }
    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array("results"=>$results));
```

This is the log from okhttp:

```
    D/OkHttp: --> POST https://admanandroid.ir/bavand/get_near_shop_cat.php
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 85
    lat=35.5092706&lng=46.1725443&search=%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1
D/OkHttp: --> END POST (85-byte body)
```

and this is the exact URL that works fine in browser:

```
https://admanandroid.ir/bavand/get_near_shop_cat.php?lat=35.5092706&lng=46.1725443&search=%22%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1%22
```

I try with GET but the same result. the response is empty. i think the problem is the 'search' query. if you look at the browser URL the search have %22% in start and end of the string. but the retrofit URL does not have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

> if you look at the browser URL the search have %22% in start and end of the string. but the retrofit URL does not have it

%22 is for qoutation mark, it means your api is eexpecting your string query to be enclosed in qoutation marks. Enclose it in qoutation marks while calling retrofit function:

```java
            .getNearShopBySearch(lat,lng,"\"" + search "\"")
```

Your browser sends A GET request when you use that url but in your code, you re trying to send a POST request. Change your function to GET and pass in parameters as queries.

```java
@GET("get_near_shop_cat.php")
Observable<NearShopLocationModel> getNearShopBySearch(@Query("lat") Double lat, @Query("lng") Double lng, @Query("search") String search);
```

Comment: I try that but the same result. the response is empty. i think the problem is the 'search' query. if you look at the browser URL the search have %22% in the start and end of the string. but the retrofit URL does not have it.

Comment: @ShadmanAdman your search string is in another language, you have to encode it before sending it to retrofit

Comment: @ShadmanAdman sorry, just checked again. The problem is that your the api endpoint is expecting your string to be qenclosed in qoutation marks, %22 is encoding for **"**

Comment: @ShadmanAdman Before sending your string to retrofit, enclose it in qoutation marks, like this: `"\"" + searchQuery + "\""`

Comment: Can you post the log from okhttp after trying this?

Comment: It actually works now. But why did this happen? something wrong with php code or what? It doesn't make sense!

Comment: this is the log : `D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://admanandroid.ir/bavand/get_near_shop_cat.php?lat=35.5092706&lng=46.1725443&search=%22%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%BE%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1%22 (206ms)
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    vary: Accept-Encoding`

Comment: @ShadmanAdman for some reason, your PHP code looks for qoutation marks in your string, maybe it has something to do with double qoutes in `$search = $_GET["search"];  ` (Not very knowledgeable on php)

Comment: Thank you. you save my time.